# Validar que una Form no permita hacer acciones en otro lado (diálogo modal)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Necesito validar que una form no permita hacer ninguna accion en otro lado de un programa, o sea que si esta abierta la form sobre una form padre, no permita hacer acciones en la form padre o cerrar la form padre sin antes cerrar la form que se tiene abierta, estoy en visual studio con c#, necesito ayuda con eso, alguien que me ayude

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás buscando es abrir un formulario como un **cuadro de diálogo modal**.

Usando [`Form.ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
FormularioHijo formModal = new FormularioHijo();

//Se abre como modal (pasando this para que sea modal del form actual)

if (formModal.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {

     // El hijo devolvió OK

} else {

     // El hijo devolvió Cancelar

}
formModal.Dispose();
```

---

Y, dentro del formulario hijo, se puede setear un botón para que devuelva `Ok`:

[image: Propiedades del botón]